# Train neural network for contour detection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to train a  convolutional neural network to detect edges in an image, I want to use [BSDS500 dataset](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html#bsds500) for that, but I'm confused for how to train it, as the parameters are in a .mat file and the input are .jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Why bother?  Why not just use a standard edge detection kernel?  High responses from the kernel will give an indication of edges.  Using a CNN is overkill... unless I'm not understanding your question.  Do you want to use a CNN to perform **segmentation**?

Comment: I was going to use it for edge detection of the lane so it can be detected in all kinds of lighting conditions, but I just used HSV masks for that in it works in almost all kind of lighting conditions.